# Float element only if remaining width is at least x pixels

Tags: css, css-float

I have an element whose width is not known in advance, which I want to float to the left, but only if it leaves at least x amount of space on the right for some text. Tried something like this:

```
#image { float: left }
#text  { min-width: 30em; }

<img id="image" src="...>
<p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
```

But this does not work because the width of #text is considered to include the float.

How can I make the float conditional on the amount of space left to its right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: http://css-tricks.com/minimum-paragraph-widths/.

Basic idea is to add a `p::before { width: 10em; }` rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive/adaptive design and arrange your elements differently in different screen resolutions done so with using css3 @ media screen

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) and (max-width: 1280px) { 
    .classname { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Does not help given that the size of the element to be floated is not known in advance, and could differ across multiple instances in the document.